# Winsock receive data

Tags: c#, winsock

I'm trying to send a very large information to the server,(size 11000) and am having a problem. The information does not reach complete.

Look the code:

On my server , there is a loop.

```
    do
    {

        Tick = Environment.TickCount;

        Listen.AcceptClient();
        Listen.Update();
    }
```

Listen.update

```
    public static void UpdateClient(UserConnection client)
    {
        string data = null;
        Decoder utf8Decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
       // byte[] buffer = new byte[client.TCPClient.Available];
            //try
            //{
                //client.TCPClient.GetStream().
            //    client.TCPClient.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            //}
            //catch
            //{
            //   int code = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetExceptionCode();
            //  Console.WriteLine("Erro Num: " + code);
            //}
            //data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            //Console.WriteLine("Byte is: " + ReadFully(client.TCPClient.GetStream(), 0));
            Console.WriteLine("Iniciando");
            byte[] buffer = ReadFully(client.TCPClient.GetStream(), 0);
            int charCount = utf8Decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Char[] chars = new Char[charCount];
            int charsDecodedCount = utf8Decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, chars, 0);

            foreach (Char c in chars)
            {
                data = data + String.Format("{0}", c);
            }

            int buffersize = buffer.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("Byte is: " + buffer.Length);


            Console.WriteLine("Data is: " + data);
            Console.WriteLine("Size is: " + data.Length);
            Server.Network.ReceiveData.SelectPacket(client.Index, data);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Reads data from a stream until the end is reached. The
    /// data is returned as a byte array. An IOException is
    /// thrown if any of the underlying IO calls fail.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The stream to read data from</param>
    /// <param name="initialLength">The initial buffer length</param>
    public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream stream, int initialLength)
    {
        // If we've been passed an unhelpful initial length, just
        // use 32K.
        if (initialLength < 1)
        {
            initialLength = 32768;
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[initialLength];
        int read = 0;

        int chunk;

        chunk = stream.Read(buffer, read, buffer.Length - read);

        checkreach:
            read += chunk;

            // If we've reached the end of our buffer, check to see if there's
            // any more information
            if (read == buffer.Length)
            {
                int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();
                // End of stream? If so, we're done
                if (nextByte == -1)
                {
                    return buffer;
                }
                // Nope. Resize the buffer, put in the byte we've just
                // read, and continue
                byte[] newBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length * 2];
                Array.Copy(buffer, newBuffer, buffer.Length);
                newBuffer[read] = (byte)nextByte;
                buffer = newBuffer;
                read++;
                goto checkreach;
            }

        // Buffer is now too big. Shrink it.
        byte[] ret = new byte[read];
        Array.Copy(buffer, ret, read);
        return ret;
    }
```

Listen.AcceptClient

```
    //Tem alguém querendo entrar na putaria? ;D
    if (listener.Pending())
    {
        //Adicionamos ele na lista
        Clients.Add(new UserConnection(listener.AcceptTcpClient(), Clients.Count()));
```

And this is my winsock server.

Anyone have tips or a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Start here: [Winsock FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/). It will explain a number of things you need to know, including that you are unlikely in a single call to `Read()` to read all of the data that was sent. Every single TCP program needs to include somewhere logic that will receive data via some type of looping, and in most cases also logic to interpret the data being received to identify boundaries between individual elements of the received data (e.g. logical messages, etc. … the only exception is when the application protocol dictates that the whole transmission from connection to closure represents a single "unit", in which case the only boundary that matters is the end of the stream).

In addition (to address just some of the many things wrong in the little bit of code you included here):

- **Don't** use `TcpClient.Available`; it's not required in *correct* code.
- **Don't** use `Marshal.GetExceptionCode()` to retrieve exception information for managed exceptions
- **Don't** use `Convert.ToInt32()` when your value *already is an instance of `System.Int32`*. And more generally, don't use `Convert` at all in scenarios where a simple cast would accomplish the same thing (even a cast isn't needed here, but I can tell from the code here what your general habit is…you should break that habit).
- **Don't** just ignore exceptions. Either do something to actually *handle* them, or let them propagate up the call stack. There's no way the rest of the code in your `UpdateClient()` method could work if an exception was thrown by the `Read()` method, but you go ahead and execute it all anyway.
- **Don't** use the `Flush()` method on a `NetworkStream` object. It does nothing (it's there only because the `Stream` class requires it).
- **Do** use `Stream.ReadAsync()` instead of dedicating a thread to each connection
- **Do** catch exceptions by including the exception type and a variable to accept the exception object reference
- **Do** use a *persistent* `Decoder` object to decode UTF8-encoded text (or any other variable-byte-length text encoding), so that if a character's encoded representation spans multiple received buffers, the text is still decoded properly.

And finally:

- **Do** post [a *good*, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is simply not possible to answer a question with any sort of preciseness if it doesn't include a proper, complete code example.

**Addendum:**

- **Don't** use the `goto` statement. Use a proper loop (e.g. `while`). Had you used a proper loop, you probably would have avoided the bug in your code where you fail to branch back to the actual `Read()` call.
- **Don't** expect the `Read()` method to fill the buffer you passed it. Not only (as I already mentioned above) is there no guarantee that all of the data sent will be returned in a single call to `Read()`, there is no guarantee that the entire buffer you pass to `Read()` will be filled before `Read()` returns.
- **Don't** read one byte at a time. That's one of the surest ways to kill performance and/or to introduce bugs. In your own example, I don't see anything obviously wrong – you only (intend to) read the single byte when looking for more data and then (intend to) go back to reading into a larger buffer – but it's not required (just try to read more data normally…that gets you the same information without special cases in the code that can lead to bugs and in any case make the code harder to understand).
- **Do** look at other examples and tutorials of networking code. Reinventing the wheel may well eventually lead to a good solution, but odds are low of that and it is a lot more time-consuming and error-prone than following someone else's good example.

I will reiterate: please read the Winsock FAQ. It has a lot of valuable information that everyone who wants to write networking code needs to know.

I will also reiterate: you cannot get a precise answer without a [**COMPLETE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code example.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but my problem persist...question edited.